how to have sections as image buttons on landing page big cartel
i would like to know how i can make the landing page of my big cartel site have picture buttons, instead of products. i want each of my sections to be offered as picture buttons when you arrive, not just as a word in the drop down menu.
as an example, i want a grid of square pictures on the landing page...one of bottles, one of cereal boxes etc.. clicking on the picture of bottles will lead you to a page that has all of my listings of bottles of soaps, clicking the cereal boxes picture leads you to the page listing all the boxed cereal i'm selling.... and so on.
i have searched and searched and i can't find any information on this at all. any help or advise would be so appreciated!

bigcartel is a business, so: have you contacted their support? Because that's step one: they are the authority on what their platform lets you do, so if you want to do something that you can't find docs for, it's a good bet they intentionally don't let you do that. You should contact them to double-check whether that's the case or not.
